# External drive not showing in Dolphin

Tags: 22.04, hard-drive, usb-drive, dolphin

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop system. I have a number of external USB drives that I connect as needed. Usually, on plugging in the drive and powering them up they appear in Nautilus and Dolphin (File Manager) within a few seconds.

One drive however does not appear in Dolphin. It appears in Nautilus and is usable from there, but despite my best efforts of restarting the program and such, it will not show in the *Removable Devices* list in Dolphin. Other drives do so without problems.

Anyone have any idea how to solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Check if the drive is hidden, by right clicking over 'Removable Devices'

Comment: Dolphin doesn't even have a "removable devices" category, and I too am having problems with viewing a USB-connected camera.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the *Devices* section of Dolphin hidden. To unhide it you can follow these steps:

1. Click on the hamburger icon on the top-right then click *Show Panels*.
2. Toggle the *Show Hidden Places* option.

   [image: Show Hidden Places option in Dolphin]
3. Then you'll see the *Devices* section as *hidden*. <kbd>Right-click</kbd> on the title of that section and you'll see a *Hide Section 'Devices'* option that allows you to unhide it.

   [image: Hide Section 'Devices' option in Dolphin]